# How do I open a SQL CE4 .sdf database file?

Tags: sql-server-ce-4

I installed Microsoft WebMatrix, which, I believe comes with SQL Server CE4. I've tried opening the SDF file in SQL Management Studio (SQL 2008), but I get the following error message:

> -------- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio:
>   There is no editor available for
>   'C:\efTest\App_Data\SchoolRepository.sdf'.
>
> Make sure the application for the file
>   type (.sdf) is installed.

How do I view/modify my .sdf database?

I see there is a similar question on StackOverflow (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070860/sql-compact-4-0-cant-open-read-sdf-file) but I would really like to use Management Studio if I can, and not another 3rd party tool.

Comment: LINQPad works well (http://www.linqpad.net/). It can connect to 3.5 and 4.0 SQL CE files.

Comment: @blins: I think this should be an answer. It works very well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download sql ce through web api just follow this link

**[visual-studio-tools-for-sql-serverl](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/12/visual-studio-tools-for-sql-server.html)**

to do that.

Answer (score 19):

Have you tried the **[SQL Server Compact Toolbox?](http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/)**

or the **[SQL Compact Query Analyzer?](http://sqlcequery.codeplex.com/)**

Comment: I was not able to use SQL Server Compact Toolbox at all, waited for 5 mins and gave up.
But SQL Compact Query Analyzer is really snappy. 3 MB download, requires an install but really snappy and works

Comment: I published a new drop of SQL Compact Query Analyzer a few days ago :)

Answer (score 4):

Here are a couple which have worked quite well for me in terms of connecting to SQL CE 3.5 and 4.0 databases:

**[LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)** - (See my remark to question) It works quite well plus it allows for specifying LINQ or SQL for queries.

**[CompactView](http://sourceforge.net/p/compactview/home/Home/)** - Seems pretty full featured + install creates a nice Windows file association so one can simply double-click to open/connect to *.sdf* files for instance.

Answer (score 0):

All of the other options require SQL CE 4.0 Database Provider installed on your machine.

This one doesn't need provider http://sqlcequery.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio 2015, 2013, 2012, 2010, try  SqlCeToolbox.4.5.0.3.vsix. It is SQL Server Compact/SQLite Toolbox for Visual Studio.

The link:
http://www.sokhawin.com/how-to-open-sql-compact-edition-file-sdf-in-visual-studio-or-linqpad/

It has ability to open and edit.