# where is data stored?

Tags: c#, .net, database, asp.net-mvc-3

[image]i am designing a project in .net 4.0 using mvc3. I am using two attribute `name` and `fname`(father name).

my controller class:

loginController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcMovie.Models;

namespace MvcMovie.Controllers
{ 
    public class loginController : Controller
    {
        private logindata db = new logindata();

        //
        // GET: /login/

        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.loginobj.ToList());
        }

        //
        // GET: /login/Details/5

        public ViewResult Details(int id)
        {
          //  login login = db.loginobj.Find(id);
            login login = db.loginobj.Find(2) ;
            return View(login);
        }

        //
        // GET: /login/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        } 

        //
        // POST: /login/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(login login)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.loginobj.Add(login);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");  
            }

            return View(login);
        }
        
        //
        // GET: /login/Edit/5
 
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

model class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
login.cs

namespace MvcMovie.Models
{
    public class login
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string name{get; set;}
        public string fname { get; set; }
    }
    public class logindata : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<login> loginobj { get; set; }
    }
}
```

view.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcMovie.Models.login>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            name
        </th>
        <th>
            fname
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.fname)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

I want to ask that where is data stored which is created by me? means how can I see that table of entries which is done by me?

whenever i click of .sdf file then there is a problem occured as shown in following picture, what should i do to solve this problem. should i installed something. i installed visual studio 2010 and sql server 2008.

Comment: Pushpendra - no need to copy the same comment three times : ) A simple google search for "This is not a valid SQL Server Compact Database file or this file version is not supported by current SQL Server Compact Engine" brings us to the solution as the _very first_ result of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070860/sql-compact-4-0-cant-open-read-sdf-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you're using Microsoft SQL CE to store your application data. If this is the case, take a look at the App_Data folder in Solution Explorer. You should see a file with .sdf extension there. Just make sure to select Show All Files icon in Solution Explorer. More details [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/05/ef-code-first-and-data-scaffolding-with-the-asp-net-mvc-3-tools-update.aspx).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sir whenever i click on .sdf file then this error is occured "This is not a valid SQL Server Compact Database file or this file version is not supported by current SQL Server Compact Engine."  please suggest me what should i do for it.?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070860/sql-compact-4-0-cant-open-read-sdf-file - So, I think you must install Visual Studio SP1 to get tooling support for SQL CE 4 within Visual Studio. Download it here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=75568aa6-8107-475d-948a-ef22627e57a5

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install Visual Studio SP1, because the tutorial you are running is thinking you are using Visual Studio Express.

You can get it here:

http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appsxml=&appid=VS2010SP1Pack

Answer (score 0):

it looks like its done through

> private logindata db = new
>   logindata();

Do you have that part in details?

Comment: Sir whenever i click on .sdf file then this error is occured "This is not a valid SQL Server Compact Database file or this file version is not supported by current SQL Server Compact Engine."  please suggest me what should i do for it.?

Answer (score 0):

That logindata DBContext looks like it was created by Entity Framework. That's pointing to a database somewhere, and that database is where you'd go to find your data. You could look in web.config for a connection string that has the database info, or if your project has a .edmx file in it open that and see what its pointing at.

Comment: Sir whenever i click on .sdf file then this error is occured "This is not a valid SQL Server Compact Database file or this file version is not supported by current SQL Server Compact Engine."  please suggest me what should i do for it.?